# Why is UIButton not working after animating downwards along y axis using CABasicAnimation()?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I cannot use the UIButton IBAction after animating it downwards.
I have tried to bring it to the top layer in the superview using

```
cardOneButton.superview?.bringToFront(cardOneButton)
```

This brings the button to the topmost layer but I still cannot trigger the IBAction using button tap.

I have tried

```
cardOneButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

but this thing also does not work.

**cardOneButton is the name of the IBOutlet for a button placed in a view.**

Code for animating the button:

```
func animateCardOneButton(_ cardOneLabel: UIButton){
        let startX = cardOneButton.frame.origin.x + (cardOneButton.frame.size.width / 2)
        let startY = cardOneButton.frame.origin.y + (cardOneButton.frame.size.height / 2)
        let endX = startX
        let endY = startY + 280
        let animation = baseAnimation(startX, startY, endX, endY)
        cardOneButton.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
```

where baseAnimation(_ startX:, _ startY:, _ endX:, _ endY:) is defined as:

```
func baseAnimation(_ startX: CGFloat, _ startY: CGFloat, _ endX: CGFloat, _ endY: CGFloat) -> CABasicAnimation{
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY)
        animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: endX, y: endY)
        animation.duration = 0.5
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        return animation
    }
```

Comment: Post a bit more detail... are you animating your button out of its superview? are you animating its layer? Show your code.

Comment: You are animating the ***layer*** - not the button itself. If you check, after the animation finishes you'll be able "tap the button" by tapping the location where the button started (because that's where its frame still is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example that will show you the difference...

It will start like this:

[image]

You'll be able to tap each of the red buttons.

After running the animation, it will look like this:

[image]

You'll be able to tap "Tap Me 2" because we animated **its frame** instead of its *Layer*.

You *cannot* tap "Tap Me 1" because we animated its *Layer*, but... if you then tap "Label 1" you'll see that "Tap Me 1" button highlights and calls its `.touchUpInside` action.

That's because "Label 1" is showing the original frame of "Tap Me 1" --- and *that frame is still there!*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cardOneButton: UIButton!
    var cardTwoButton: UIButton!
    var labelOne: UILabel!
    var labelTwo: UILabel!

    var runAnimButton: UIButton!
    var infoLabel2: UILabel!
    var infoLabel1: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        labelOne = UILabel()
        labelOne.text = "Label 1"
        labelOne.textAlignment = .center
        labelOne.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        view.addSubview(labelOne)
        
        labelTwo = UILabel()
        labelTwo.text = "Label 2"
        labelTwo.textAlignment = .center
        labelTwo.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        view.addSubview(labelTwo)
        
        infoLabel1 = UILabel()
        infoLabel1.text = "Result:"
        infoLabel1.textAlignment = .center
        infoLabel1.backgroundColor = .yellow
        infoLabel1.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        view.addSubview(infoLabel1)
        
        infoLabel2 = UILabel()
        var s = ""
        s += "Tap each red button...\n\n"
        s += "Then tap the Animate button...\n\n"
        s += "Then try to tap each red button...\n\n"
        s += "AND try to Tap each Label"
        infoLabel2.text = s
        infoLabel2.textAlignment = .center
        infoLabel2.numberOfLines = 0
        infoLabel2.backgroundColor = .green
        infoLabel2.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        view.addSubview(infoLabel2)
        
        cardOneButton = UIButton()
        cardOneButton.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        cardOneButton.setTitle("Tap Me 1", for: [])
        cardOneButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .highlighted)
        view.addSubview(cardOneButton)
        
        cardTwoButton = UIButton()
        cardTwoButton.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        cardTwoButton.setTitle("Tap Me 2", for: [])
        cardTwoButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .highlighted)
        view.addSubview(cardTwoButton)
        
        runAnimButton = UIButton()
        runAnimButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        runAnimButton.setTitle("Animate", for: [])
        runAnimButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .highlighted)
        view.addSubview(runAnimButton)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        [runAnimButton, cardOneButton, cardTwoButton].forEach { b in
            b.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 120, height: 40))
        }
        
        runAnimButton.center.x = view.center.x
        runAnimButton.frame.origin.y = view.safeAreaInsets.top + 20
        
        cardOneButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 40, y: runAnimButton.frame.maxY + 20)
        cardTwoButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: cardOneButton.frame.maxX + 40, y: runAnimButton.frame.maxY + 20)

        labelOne.frame = cardOneButton.frame
        labelTwo.frame = cardTwoButton.frame
        
        infoLabel1.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: cardOneButton.frame.maxY + 20, width: 280, height: 30)

        let sz = infoLabel2.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: 280, height: 300), withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow)
        
        infoLabel2.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: infoLabel1.frame.maxY + 20, width: 280, height: sz.height + 16)
        
        cardOneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cardTwoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        runAnimButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doAnim(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        guard let b = sender as? UIButton,
              let t = b.currentTitle
        else { return }
        infoLabel1.text = "Result: \(t) was tapped!"
    }
    
    @objc func doAnim(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        
        // original LAYER animation
        animateCardOneButton(cardOneButton)
        
        // animate frame of BUTTON itself
        animateButton(cardTwoButton)
    }

    func animateButton(_ aButton: UIButton) -> Void {

        let startY = aButton.frame.origin.y
        let endY = startY + 280

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            aButton.frame.origin.y = endY
        })
        
    }
    
    func animateCardOneButton(_ aButton: UIButton){
        let startX = aButton.frame.origin.x + (aButton.frame.size.width / 2)
        let startY = aButton.frame.origin.y + (aButton.frame.size.height / 2)
        let endX = startX
        let endY = startY + 280
        let animation = baseAnimation(startX, startY, endX, endY)
        aButton.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
    
    func baseAnimation(_ startX: CGFloat, _ startY: CGFloat, _ endX: CGFloat, _ endY: CGFloat) -> CABasicAnimation{
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY)
        animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: endX, y: endY)
        animation.duration = 0.5
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        return animation
    }

}
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation! Now I have understood the difference. Thanks a lot!